# Is there a way to run a single Jest test within an 'each' clause?

Tags: jestjs

I'm wondering if there's a way to run a single test that is inside of a `test.each` clause in Jest.

Example test.each clause from the docs:

```js
test.each([
  {a: 1, b: 1, expected: 2},
  {a: 1, b: 2, expected: 3},
  {a: 2, b: 1, expected: 3},
])('.add($a, $b)', ({a, b, expected}) => {
  expect(a + b).toBe(expected);
});
```

The test names are generated at runtime, so it didn't seem like `jest -t <name>` would work, and sure enough, I tried and all tests were skipped. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[(It's OK To Ask and Answer Your Own Questions)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.96098844.1613866090.1630841201-792985124.1628514364)

If you run into this problem, know that `jest -t <name>` works with substrings, and so in my case I just had to use a substring of the test name.

The full name was not working for some reason and I was misattributing this to the runtime name generation, which is perfectly compatible.